# javascript string validator failing to validate correctly using startsWith()

Tags: javascript, powerapps

I have this very simple validator

```
if (!toString(aAccountNumber).startsWith('A')) {
      alert('AAccountNumber must start with the capital letter A');
      return;
    }
```

I then call this when pressing a button on a web page but not matter what I type in the input field, even starting with an A like A112233 it still fails and puts up the alert

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The information you provide is not enough to know what the actual problem is.

Comment: What is `aAccountNumber` and what is `toString()`? but you proably want `aAccountNumber.toString()` instead of `toString(aAccountNumber)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to use `toString`, it must be called on the object to test, you were probably just getting undefined.

```js
if (!aAccountNumber.toString().startsWith('A')) {
  alert('AAccountNumber must start with the capital letter A');
}
```

Also note that a text input value is already a string so you probably don't need to call toString at all.

Comment: Its weird, the IDE I am using doesnt show toString() as an option unless I use toString(foo) but inDeed it works just fine the way you put it it was silly of me to assume it did not work after reading docs I just assume the IDE would actually have a clue but it seems not, thank you MSFT and powerpages javascript IDE